# Regarding null pointers and an assignment C

Tags: c

I'm stuck with my assignment and i can't seem to get it working, your help would be appreciated!:)

Task was to list prime numbers between a min max passed from program arguments (swap min&max if in wrong order). I was told to protect against null pointers and that there is some problem with not checking argv(?).(I won't include the prime part since that works )

Main.c

```
void proc(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    int min,max;
    min=atoi(argv[1]);
    max=atoi(argv[2]);

    if(min>max)
      {
       swap(min, max); 
       printf("Min&max swapped!");
      }

    if(argc!=3)
      {
    printf("Please set 2 numbers as interval");
    exit(EXIT_FAILURE);
      }

    prime(min,max);

    return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}

int main(int min,int max)
{
    proc(min, max);
}
```

Swap.c

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
{
    int c = *a;
    *a = *b;
    *b = c;
}
```

Comment: You aren't passing in an int-pointer to swap, just their values, you should use the address-of operator.

Comment: `swap(min, max); ` should be `swap(&min, &max); `. `swap` function should have an if statement to check whether `a` or `b` is a null pointer.

Comment: you'd want to check `argc` before `atoi`ing `argv`. if the user didn't provide to numbers, you will get a segmentation fault

Comment: Please check `argc` *before* you try accessing `argv`.

Comment: `int* c` .... ?? enable compiler warnings.

Comment: Also, `main` expects `argc` and `argv`. calling your program now will put the number of aguments in `min` and a pointer (memory address) to an array of pointers to your arguments in `max`

Comment: `int main(int min,int max)` is an invalid signature. YOur code invokes undefined behaviour. You cannot just use whatever signature for `main` you want.

Comment: Don't edit your problem in the answer! This is vandalism!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check `argc`value before accessing `argv` that way you eliminate the chance of accessing out of bound memory.

Also swap  should get address of min and max so that the change can be reflected.

```
swap(&min,&max);
void swap(int *x,int *y)
{
   int t=*x;
   *x=*y;
   *y=t;
}
```

#### How you should go about?

```
if( argc != 3)
{
    printf("[%s]:[progname num1 num2]\n");
    return 0;
}

...
...
min = atoi(argv[1]);
..
max = ..
if(max<min)
 swap(&max,&min);
```

Comment: I corrected the code based on your input, one more question if you don't mind, 
I added two lines to swap.c     
     if(!a)return 0;
     if(!b)return 0;
that works as a null pointer check, right?

Comment: You've misspelled `||`.  And related minor quibble: I can't think of a good reason to recommend `argc > 3 || argc < 3` over `argc != 3`.

Comment: @JohnBollinger.: yes i mistyped and went a bit odd diection..thanks

Answer (score 2):

```
int min,max;
...
  swap(min, max);
```

Okay, so you pass the `swap` function two `int`s.

```
void swap(int *a,int *b)
```

But `swap` expects two `int*`s. That can't be good.

Also:

```
int* c = *a;
```

Hmm, `a` is of type `int*`, so `*a` is of type `int`. So why are you assigning it to a variable of type `int*`? That can't be good either.

Comment: mistype that * after int in swap
so
    int c = *a;